# Putting many PropertyList's into Google App Engine datastore (in Go) and loading them again with Query.GetAll

Tags: google-app-engine, go, datastore

I am putting entities (as a `datastore.PropertyList`) into the datastore like this:

```
// save one
var plist datastore.PropertyList = make(datastore.PropertyList, 3)
plist = append(plist, datastore.Property { "name", "Mat", false, false })
plist = append(plist, datastore.Property { "age", "29", false, false })
plist = append(plist, datastore.Property { "location", "London", false, false })
key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(context, "Record", nil)
datastore.Put(context, key, &plist)

// save another one
var plist datastore.PropertyList = make(datastore.PropertyList, 3)
plist = append(plist, datastore.Property { "name", "Laurie", false, false })
plist = append(plist, datastore.Property { "age", "27", false, false })
plist = append(plist, datastore.Property { "location", "London", false, false })
key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(context, "Record", nil)
datastore.Put(context, key, &plist)
```

That all works fine (although the code above is more like pseudo code for now).  I am able to load them individually, and the `datastore.PropertyList` comes out with each field as its own `datastore.Property`.

However, when I try to retrieve many of them using a `Query`, it fails:

```
query := datastore.NewQuery("Record")

plists := make(datastore.PropertyList, 0, 10)
keys, err := query.GetAll(context, &plists)
```

I get the following error:

```
datastore: cannot load field "age" into a "datastore.Property": no such struct field
```

It seems that it doesn't complain about `Name` because that happens to be a valid property of `datastore.Property`, so how do I get it to load the items as intended, with each item in `plists` being a `datastore.PropertyList` instead of `datastore.Property`?

Comment: by the way, I am doing exactly the same as the code in this file: https://hyk-proxy.googlecode.com/svn-history/r256/trunk/v2/gae/src/go/service/user.go - specifically the `GetAllGroups` method where they are loading many items out in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the implementation to use the `PropertyLoadSaver` interface - you can see it working nicely in our new Active Record style wrapper for datastore: http://github.com/matryer/gae-records (see the `record.go` type's `Load` and `Save` methods)

Answer (score 2):

> GetAll runs the query in the given context and returns all keys that match that query, as well as appending the values to dst. The dst must be a pointer to a **slice** of structs, struct pointers, or Maps. If q is a “keys-only” query, GetAll ignores dst and only returns the keys.

And according to the [following post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/Vv-6DJjSDIo/YEytGpexhrEJ) the go datastore module doesn't support PropertyList yet.

Use a pointer to a slice of datastore.Map instead.

Also note that you need to do call `make([]T, n)` in order to make a slice of `T`, not `make(T, n)`

Answer (score 2):

Try writing your field names with a capital letter, for example, instead of `age`, write `Age`. This tells Go that your field is exported (it's similar to the concept of public variables, though it goes a bit further than that).

According to the [Go datastore documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference.html) (look at the Get method in the Functions section), a `Get` or `GetAll` method call, will return an `ErrFieldMismatch` "when a field is to be loaded into a different type than the one it was stored from, **or when a field is missing or unexported in the destination struct**. ErrFieldMismatch is only returned if dst is a struct pointer.". My best guess is that since you stored it as a `PropertyList` with unexported names, and since the datastore is flexible in its models, it will take the original values as unexported, due to their lowercase letters.

I am currently having the same error, but I managed to track it down to being due to some empty fields.

If this solves your problem, please let me know.